# Developer Story: Recommended Reading overflows

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

On my Developer Story, I have one Recommended Reading, and the whole text overflows from the box. I have attached a screenshot.

The text was copied and pasted from a review I left on GoodReads.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your report, it's now fixed and will be live after one of our next production builds.